# Rails 3.1 Flowplayer Gem install

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, flowplayer

I am attempting to install the Flowplayer helper gem for use in a Rails 3.1 app with Ruby 1.9.3 installed on OSX Lion via RVM.

`gem install flowplayer`

completes normally, as does

`echo "gem 'flowplayer'" >> Gemfile`

`bundle install`

When I attempt to run `rails g flowplayer`

I get:

```
/Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/flowplayer-0.1.2/lib/flowplayer/railties/generator/install_generator.rb:3:in `<module:Generator>': uninitialized constant Flowplayer::Rails::Generators (NameError)
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/flowplayer-0.1.2/lib/flowplayer/railties/generator/install_generator.rb:2:in `<module:Flowplayer>'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/flowplayer-0.1.2/lib/flowplayer/railties/generator/install_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/flowplayer-0.1.2/lib/flowplayer/railtie.rb:6:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `call'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `block in load_generators'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `each'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `load_generators'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:402:in `block in load_generators'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:402:in `load_generators'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:109:in `load_generators'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators.rb:331:in `load_generators_from_railties!'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators.rb:289:in `lookup'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators.rb:149:in `find_by_namespace'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/generators.rb:166:in `invoke'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've dodged this problem by monkeypatching `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@flowplayer/gems/flowplayer-0.1.2/lib/flowplayer/railties/generator/install_generator.rb` file.

I've changed it from:

```
module Flowplayer
  module Generator
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      (...)
    end
  end
end
```

to:

```
module Flowplayer::Generator
    class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
      (...)
    end
end
```

Don't know why, but it works.